# Server don't receive data send by iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, nsstring, nsdata

I'm send a string to my server (PHP) with the code below:

```
    NSString* str = @"teststring";
    NSData* dataToSend = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    uint8_t *dataBytes = (uint8_t *)[dataToSend bytes];
    uint64_t length = dataToSend.length;

    [outputStream write:dataBytes maxLength:length];
```

The problem with this is code, is that I don't receive the string (Server recognize that a user enter and I receive a handshake in Xcode console) I test others codes and works very well (receive data), but in this time I'm trying by my own. I believe I'm not converting the message to the appropriate format, and that's why the message is not being received, am I right? If so how I could convert this message to the appropriate format?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the output stream has space for writing that many bytes at the moment when you call the `write:...` method?  You should only call `write:...` on an output stream from within your `stream:handleEvent:` delegate method, and only if the event code is `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable`.

And you **must** check the result to see how many bytes were actually written.  If it is fewer bytes than you sent, you must enqueue the remaining data to resend later, whenever your `stream:handleEvent:` delegate method gets called again.

For more details, see:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/WritingOutputStreams.html